# Prompting user to save file using a 'Save-as' dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, save-as

I currently have this code:

```
function download(filename, text) {
        var pom = document.createElement('a');
        pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
        pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
        pom.click();
}

download('test.html', string);
```

The `string` contains a lot of html code that gets written in an .html file.
The above code is working perfectly:
On a button click, the browser (chrome) automatically downloads an html file with the string content written in it.

Now, what I want to do is, instead of chrome downloading the file automatically, it should open a "save-as" dialog box and ask the user the location and name of the file, and then download it to that location.

A quick simple reply would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think it will always use the default behavior, because this is what the user expects.

Comment: Well, in my case, user should be able to set the location and name of the file to be saved...

Comment: That will happen automatically if the browser has not instructed their browser to do otherwise. But maybe you can force it by supplying a different mime type via the `type` attribute for the link.

Comment: Can't find any such attribute to open save-as dialog...

Comment: You have set your browser has all file downloaded to a default location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My browser was set to automatically download all files in default location which is why not only this file but all other files from my browser were downloaded directly without the save prompt dialogue. Changing the settings in browser to 'always ask the download location' worked.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to set the header of the file on the server, like so:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

The download attribute does not allow you to change the filename or filetype any more as it is an obvious security risk.

What you are trying to do it replicate the right-click - save-as dialogue but I'm afraid that is not possible at this time.