# Javascript download file force prompt destination

Tags: javascript, download

I'm downloading a file via javascript (the file is generated on the server) and I want to force the browser to prompt the user to choose the destination of the file. Is it possible? For instance, Chrome as an option with a default folder and I want to be able to override that option

EDIT (explaining the duplicate question)
I think it's not a duplicate because I know why the dialog is not opening, just want to ask if the behavior can be overriden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prompting user to save file using a 'Save-as' dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679842/prompting-user-to-save-file-using-a-save-as-dialog)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot override the download behaviour. A number of modern browsers save any download into a default location without prompting the user. That's how they download files, period. You cannot override this. It's a user choice in the browser's preferences whether they want to be prompted or not.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the behavior can be overridden using the File System Access API. The API exposes some methods that will override the browser's behavior.
Simply running `window.showOpenFilePicker()` in the Chrome Browser console will launch the file picker prompt.

To override the download destination prompt behavior, you can make use of the `window.showSaveFilePicker()` method.

```
// ...
const blob = new Blob(/*...*/);
// Use File System Access API
saveFileToDisk(blob, 'Some-File.txt')

async saveFileToDisk({blob, fileName}){
      try {
        const fileHandle = await self.showSaveFilePicker({
          suggestedName: fileName,
          types: [
            {
              description: "File",
              // ...
            },
          ],
        });
        const writeFile = async (fileHandle, contents) => {
          // Create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to.
          const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
          // Write the contents of the file to the stream.
          await writable.write(contents);
          // Close the file and write the contents to disk.
          await writable.close();
        };
        // write file
        writeFile(fileHandle, blob).then(() => console.log("FILE DOWNLOADED!!!"));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
}
```

For more details, check out the documentation https://web.dev/file-system-access/ and https://web.dev/browser-fs-access/

Comment: As of late Dec 2021, showSaveFilePicker is only supported on Chrome, Edge and Opera, and only if using HTTPS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker